# Spherical Plane Wave Interference

Tags: optics, waves, interference

I would like to ask this following question. In the picture below we have a spherical and plane wave. For the plane wave we have the angle between k and the x axis, that is θ. I would like to know what this angle is for the spherical wave,  =0( ̂ +  ̂).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane wave:

$$ \psi(\mathbf{x}) = Ae^{i({\mathbf{ k \cdot x}}-\omega t)} $$

is an eigenstate of the wave-vector operator:

$$ {\mathbf{\hat k}} =-i\mathbf{\nabla} $$

per:

$$ {\mathbf{\hat k}}\psi(\mathbf{x}) =-i{\mathbf{\nabla}}Ae^{i({\mathbf{ k \cdot x}}-\omega t)} $$
$$ = -iAe^{i({\mathbf{ k \cdot x}}-\omega t)}i{\mathbf{\nabla}}({\mathbf{ k \cdot x}}-\omega t )$$

$$ = {\mathbf{k}}\psi(\mathbf{x}) $$

Hence, one can define the angle of $\mathbf k$ with respect to the $x$-axis.

Moreover, this eigenvalue reflects the translation symmetry of the plane wave: if the wave is translated in the direction $\mathbf k$ by $2\pi/||k||$, the wave is unchanged.

You can't to that with a spherical wave. It has some value for $k_r$, which points in all directions, while the natural angular eigenstates have rotational symmetry (the spherical harmonics). They do not have a well defined Cartesian wave vector with which to find an angle with respect to the $x$-axis.